# What is the origin of "cut rate"?

Tags: idioms, terminology

I saw this drug store sign from 1929. Does the term "cut rate" have a pharmaceutical origin or does this just refer to "low cost"? This in a low income area, but I know pharmacies "cut" drugs with other substances so I became curious about the origin. 
[image]

Comment: [collinsdictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut) 8. verb
*If you **cut** something, you **reduce** it.* I'm not sure this question would even pass muster on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It was used  in the mid 18th century of railroad freight tariffs lower than the prevailing or published rate.  "Cut" doesn't mean "diluted" as it does with drugs. The word **cut** in this context may go back to a figure of speech based on the tally mark/measure. The rate is "a cut below" the prevailing rate.  Look up the etymology of **tally**.

Comment: @TRomano You mean the 19th century - there weren't any railroads before that!

Comment: Sorry, yes, a typo.  19th c.

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut-rate):

> marked by, offering, or making use of a reduced rate or price

Comment: This is part of the [`UP/DOWN` metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), here instantiated as a [commercial transaction](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) metaphor that involves removing metaphoric money from a metaphoric stack, thus cutting the price down, or lowering the rate. Hence _cut-rate_ like _cut-throat_, a VO compound